# How to shift right in modular arithmetic $2^n$ using only subtraction and multiplication.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, bit-strings

In modular arithmetic $2^n$ it is easy to shift left number $x$ by doing $(x\ll 1)=2x=x+x=x-(0-x)$. Shifting right on the other hand is integer division by the power of 2, e.g. $(x\gg 1)=\lfloor x/2 \rfloor$. My question: Is it possible to shift right using only addition, subtraction and multiplication?
I suspect it is not possible.

I do not have direct access to the bits of the number. I know that the operation $(x\ll (n-1)) \pmod{2^{n+1}}$ effectively gives $(x\gg 1)$ in the upper half of the bit array. This trick is not good since it requires erasing the lower half, which is not addition/subtraction/multiplication.

By squaring the number a few times it is possible to calculate $(x\&1)=x\%2=(x \pmod 2)$, because all odd numbers give $1$ and all even give $0$. This is erasing all higher bits except the lowest. But erasing lower bits leaving the higher is also questionable.

Comment: You should explain what a shift is since not everyone here has a programming background.

Comment: You have a very unusual definition of **shift right** since $x<<1$ is normally considered to be a **left** shift. And instead of $x<< (2^n-1)$ you most probably mean $x<< (n-1)$ because your expression is zero for most $n!$

Comment: Thanks, edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible for $n\geq 2$.

Suppose there is some polynomial $p(X) \in (\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z}) [X]$ such that $p(a) = \lfloor \frac{a}{2}\rfloor$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z}$.

First, set $a=0$.  Since $p(0) = 0$, the constant term of $p$ is $0$.

Next, set $a=2^{n-1}$.  Since $(2^{n-1})^2 = 2^{2n-2}$ and $2n-2 \geq n$, all the terms of $p(2^{n-1})$ are zero besides possibly the linear term.  But $p(2^{n-1}) = 2^{n-2}$, while the linear term is divisible by $2^{n-1}$, contradiction.

Comment: Alternatively you can show that $p(2)$ must be a multiple of 2 which equals 1.